# Access tag "option" in HtmlElement

Tags: c#, html

need to change this:

```
<select name="asdf">
    <option selected>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
    <option>c</option>
</select>
```

I got the `HtmlElement` but cant change it via `htmlEle.SetAttribute("value", "c");`

I want to change the selected option from **a** to **c**.

Comment: What isn't working?  Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No it just doesnt change to combo box i want to change

Comment: What exactly are you trying to change in the combo box?

Comment: the selected item of the combobox which is currently "a" i want to change to "c"

Comment: This is still underspecified. Do you want the options to be c, b, c? Sounds odd. Or do you actually want to make the third option selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have the element, you can loop through the children and update the selected attribute:

```
var ele = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("asdf");

if (ele != null)
{
    foreach (HtmlElement child in ele.Children)
    {
        child.SetAttribute("selected", "false");
        if (child.InnerText == "c")
            child.SetAttribute("selected", "true");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming: `htmlEle` is the option Element,

C#:  Please try:

```
  htmlEle.textContent = "a1";
```

to make the option appearing gas selected,

```
 htmlEle.setAttribute("selected", "true");
```

HTML/JavaScript:

You mean you want to change the display value of first option from `a` to `c`, then try below:

```
      htmlEle.innerHTML = "c";
```

to make the option appearing gas selected,

htmlEle.setAttribute("selected", "selected");

If I have an `ID` assigned to selectbox as:

```
      <select name="asdf" id="selectBox">
         <option selected>a</option>
         <option>b</option>
         <option>c</option>
       </select>
```

Then

```
  var selectElem = document.getElementById("selectBox");
  selectElem.childNodes[1].innerHTML = "a1";
```

changes value of first option as `a1`.

Comment: This is not what he wanted to do. What you wrote clears all the innerHTML of the select item. problem... :)

Comment: @gdoron: I am not working on the select element, I am updating the option element. Please refer the example in the answer and try your self.

Comment: @Downvoter: Please leave some comment to understand the issue.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this doesn't seem to do what he requested. (btw, he wants C# code, not js, as we both used.)

Comment: @gdoron: It wasn't clear in the question hence answered. Updated the answer.

Comment: @user1791339: Please check the updated answer for `c#` and let me know, if doesn't help.

Comment: thanks man hmlEle.setAttribute("selected", "true"); worked (see also answer from John Koerner)

Comment: @user1791339: It wasn't clear that you were looking for C# code so we answered the javascript way. Also we got an impression that you wanted to change the text of the option :)

Comment: true - i will do better next time!!

Answer (score 1):

This is done easily with

```
htmlEle.value = "c";
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/y2Dze/1)

Comment: Why did you remove the C# tag?  Based on the term `HtmlElement` and the `SetAttribute` call it is obvious he is loading the html in a C# webbrowser and trying to manipulate it through there.

Comment: c# doent got the member value on htmele :\

Comment: @JohnKoerner. Sorry, it wasn't obvious to me at all. The writing was and is poor. :(