# How to insert string into combobox in webbrowser?

Tags: c#, string, winforms

I'm making a winforms application in C# that has a few textboxes.
One for the name, one for subject and one for message.
Everything works except for the combobox (dropdownlist) on the website.

It's like this:

1. [a drop-down list with words]

   1. Dr
   2. Mr
   3. Mrs
   4. Miss and so on...
2. [Name] 
   enter a name
3. [Subject] 
   enter a subject line here
4. [Message] 
   enter a message here

I want to programatically insert my string of text into the drop-down list. I mean like, if I type in "mr" in my application, it should find "mr" and then check like if the list item text = "mr" then continue.
How can I do that?
I tried to do it with indexes - which works, but that's not so user-friendly.
Indexes starts from 0 and this is what my current code looks like:

```
HtmlElement hField = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("name_prefix");
hField.SetAttribute("selectedIndex", "1");
```

I want something along the lines like

```
HtmlElement hField = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("name_prefix");
hField.SetAttribute("selectedIndex", textbox1.Text);
```

but that did not work since it's a list with options and not a textbox.

Answer (score 0):

I think I just got a solution.
If I were to add a combobox in my winforms application with the name prefixes ready, then do this:

```
HtmlElement hField = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("name_prefix");
hField.SetAttribute("selectedIndex", "comboBox1.SelectedIndex");
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the name_prefix element, loop through the items until you find the right one, then select it:

```
var ele = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("asdf");

if (ele != null)
{
    foreach (HtmlElement child in ele.Children)
    {
        child.SetAttribute("selected", "false");
        if (child.InnerText == "c")
            child.SetAttribute("selected", "true");
    }
}
```

[See this answer by John Koerner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13325619/access-tag-option-in-htmlelement)

Comment: Seems like it keeps jumping down to the bottom in the drop-down list. I don't know why it does that

Comment: What does your code look like now? Have you changed "c" in my example to "Dr" or "Mrs" etc...? I have noticed that from John's answer I have linked, if you are trying to select "Mr" then it will set "Mrs" to selected as well. Some refinement could probably be made to his code.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code instead

HTMLSelectElement hfield=WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select");

hfield.value=textbox1.text

Or

HTMLSelectElement hfield=WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsById("name_prefix");

hfield.value=textbox1.text

Note:"Include mshtml namespacë".